# Exception in Tomcat7

Tags: java, exception, tomcat, tomcat7

I am not sure why this has started to happen but today I tried to use my Tomcat7 after a long time and whenever I am trying to access any application it is throwing me this error:

```
 type Exception report

 message Unable to compile class for JSP

 description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
 from fulfilling this request.

 exception

 org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP

 An error occurred at line: -1 in the jsp file: null

 Generated servlet error:
     [javac] Compiling 1 source file



    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:130)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:293)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:353)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:370)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:473)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:190)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:295)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:241)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728) note The
 full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache
 Tomcat/7.0.39 logs.
```

More details about the exception from tomcat logs:

> SEVERE: Exception:  Unable to find a javac compiler;
>   com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath. Perhaps JAVA_HOME
>   does not point to the JDK     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.CompilerAdapterFactory.getCompiler(CompilerAdapterFactory.java:140)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:969)  at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:799)   at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:320)
>     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:370)   at
>   org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:473)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:190)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:295)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:241)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
>     at com.iplanet.jato.view.ViewBeanBase.forward(ViewBeanBase.java:340)
>     at
>   com.iplanet.jato.view.ViewBeanBase.forwardTo(ViewBeanBase.java:261)
>     at
>   com.sun.identity.authentication.UI.LoginViewBean.forwardTo(LoginViewBean.java:662)
>     at
>   com.iplanet.jato.ApplicationServletBase.dispatchRequest(ApplicationServletBase.java:981)
>     at
>   com.iplanet.jato.ApplicationServletBase.processRequest(ApplicationServletBase.java:615)
>     at
>   com.iplanet.jato.ApplicationServletBase.doGet(ApplicationServletBase.java:459)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.forgerock.openam.validation.ResponseValidationFilter.doFilter(ResponseValidationFilter.java:44)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   com.sun.identity.setup.AMSetupFilter.doFilter(AMSetupFilter.java:98)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

**JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME are correctly set** Also jdk/bin is also in path.

Comment: Please post the stack trace of the root cause (see the last line of your stacktrace above)

Comment: An error occurred at line: -1 in the jsp file: null.  post the jsp file too

Comment: Something wrong with the JSP files I guess .

Comment: There is no problem with JSP. Even if i dont have a jsp in my webapp, it is throwing the error. I have added more exception traces. It seems tomcat is messed up somehow by me. Let me try to do a fresh install of it.

Answer (score 0):

Reading from http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Miscellaneous it says that this issue may be result of:

> 1. [Environment variable issue](http://marc.info/?l=tomcat-user&m=104949554010352&w=2)
> 2. [Environment issue](http://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16688) or [Ant issue](http://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=20527)
> 3. Others have had success by added JAVA_HOME/bin to their PATH. [1](http://marc.info/?l=tomcat-user&m=105525594928279&w=2) ... [2](http://marc.info/?l=tomcat-user&m=105526353505541&w=2) and make sure you are using the full JDK and not the JRE.

Comment: I have already mentioned that eviornment variables are correctly set. I have checked the enviornment variables by printing them on the command line. They point to the correct locations.

Comment: What is your CATALINA_HOME ?

Comment: Why do I need to set CATALINA_HOME?

Comment: Check This article http://forums.devshed.com/java-help-9/an-error-occurred-at-line--1-in-the-jsp-file-65627.html for a similar problem like yours (and had to do with CATALINA_HOME)

Answer (score 0):

Recheck and make sure the following things are properly set

1. JAVA_HOME environment variable is pointing to correct jdk path
2. CATALINA_HOME is pointing to the correct directory
3. CLASSPATH is set to point the correct jar files